# Show only "Read more" link

Tags: 8, nodes, navigation

How can show only "**read more**" link in node's teaser, and remove or unset other links like "add new comments" or "2 Comments" at the end of a node teaser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Through PHP. This is the correct way. The code below would go in your theme's `.theme` file.

   ```
   function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
     // Determine which links should be removed. These are CSS classes, because
     // they are used as keys in the $variables['links'] array.
     $links_to_remove = array(
       // X comments link.
       'comment-comments',
       // X new comments.
       'comment-new-comments',
       // Add new comment.
       'comment-add',
     );
     // Loop through the links and remove them.
     foreach ($variables['links'] as $css_class => $link) {
       if (in_array($css_class, $links_to_remove)) {
         unset($variables['links'][$css_class]);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Through CSS. This is not the best way, but is faster:

   ```
   .your-node-selector .node__links li.comment-comments,
   .your-node-selector .node__links li.comment-new-comments,
   .your-node-selector .node__links li.comment-add {
     display: none;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness, My problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Drupal 8 uses views to display teasers.

If that is the case, all you have to do is edit the teaser view and change `Content: Teaser` to `Content: Fields` and then just add the fields you want. Basically, you can create your own custom teaser.